# Reasons and benefits for using a literal in asp over html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am fairly new to asp.net so this may seem like a stupid question, but:

I am attempting to modify a pre-exsiting help menu in a web-app.

In this menu the previous developer, just used three literals seperated by paragraphs and a button linking to a 100 page manual. (i know doesn't seem to be much help, hence why i was planning to update and fix this)

What i had in mind was setting something up like a menu that would link to the different section of the page when the title is clicked.

So something along these lines:

```
<h1>Menu Contents</h1> 
<ol>
<li>section1</li>
<li>section2</li>
<li>etc</li>
 </ol>
```

After the contents section i would have the first section with it's details.

What i am wondering is why would i use asp-literals over just sticking to html?
So basically i would like to know what are the benefits or reasons for using asp literals and i guess when is it that i should use them?

I've attempted to find the solution to this on my own, but the only related matters i have been able to find have to deal with people arguing whether literals or labels are the best option so it's not entirely helpful.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You generally use literals if you want to be able to control the text you display programmatically. Say your page has a way to edit the section titles of your manual, for instance. Or say your manual is in multiple languages and you want the user to be able to set her language and see the section titles displayed in that language.
In your case, by what you're saying, I infer none of this applies and your manual is quite static. In that case I would stick to simple HTML.

Comment: That is not something i considered about the manual, however like you said it just links to a pdf so i don't believe it applies, but that is a good point and something i plan to look into in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's been done that way so it would allow the links to be built dynamically, something like:

```
litMenuItem1.Text = "<a href=\"section1.aspx\">section1</a>";
```

thus giving full control over the output? There are better ways to do that however.